# div placement issue

Tags: html, css, xhtml

I have a container div, which will contain 3 or more divs

```
<div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</div>
```

Now, I want to place div's as

```
[container-div]
   [1st div]      [2nd div]      [3rd div]
   [4th div]      [5th div] 
[/container-div]
```

How to achieve following?

Thanks

Comment: Why don't you use table instead?

Comment: Tables seem reasonably adequate for the problem you have.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you always want 3 divs in a row you can add a class to them and style them like this:

```
.float {
    float: left;
    width: 33%;
}
```

If you want to have margins you should notate them also in % and substract the margin from the width.

Comment: is there any way I can fix width for main-container div, so that it will not expand in any case?

Comment: Based on Pawels fiddle you can of course do that. Have a look at this:
http://jsfiddle.net/nyC5L/1/

Comment: Also, if you know that your outer container will be a fixed width (lets assume 600px) you can also work with pixels instead of percent since 600/3 is 200px per inner div.

Answer (score 0):

```
<style type="text/css">
#one,#two,#three,#four,#five{
float:left;
}

.clearfix{
clear:both;
}

</style>

<div id="container">
  <div id="one"></div>
  <div id="two"></div>
  <div id="three"></div>
  <div class="clearfix"></div>
  <div id="four"></div>
  <div id="five"></div>
</div>
```

just try it

Answer (score 0):

Three ways that I can think of.

First, you can use float to set their position (style='float:left/right'). However, this will cause them to overflow the containing div, unless you follow them with another div with clear:both (`<div style='clear:both'></div>`), as shown by Anish.

Second, you can use a table or the display property table, table-row, and table-cell.
e.g:

```
<div style='display:table'>
  <div style='display:table-row'>
    <div style='display:table-cell'>div 1</div>
    <div style='display:table-cell'>div 2</div>
    <div style='display:table-cell'>div 3</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

And finally, you can use the display property inline-block, which removes the linebreak at the end of the div while allowing you to keep the fixed width.
e.g:

```
<div style='display:inline-block;width:33%'>div 1</div>
<div style='display:inline-block;width:33%'>div 2</div>
<div style='display:inline-block;width:33%'>div 3</div>
<br />
<div style='display:inline-block;width:33%'>div 4</div>
<div style='display:inline-block;width:33%'>div 5</div>
```

Comment: inner div's are generated on-fly, so can't put <br/>

Comment: What do you mean by on-fly? Strictly speaking, you shouldn't need the br. Because every 3 divs widths add up to 99%, they should wrap automatically, but I think explicitly including a break is just good practice. If you share what you mean by on-fly, I'll be happy to show how you can include it.

Comment: on-fly means through programming loop

Comment: @I-M-JM: I guessed that, I meant what kind of programming loop? Most languages have some form of counter you can use to track loops, for instance in php you might use `if($i%3 == 0 && $i>0)echo '<br />';`